# Где найти "ресурс", откуда система берет языки?

Tags: android, locale, accessibility

Я начал делать проект, в котором автоматизирую действия с помощью AccessibilityServices, но столкнулся с проблемой локализации проекта, а точнее в том как мне найти нужный элемент на экране, если названия различаются в зависимости как от версии системы, так и в зависимости от производителя.

Надпись "**Разрешить**" (в "ru" версии системы) будет называть "**Allow permission**" (в "en"), поэтому воспользоваться переводчиком не вариант (т.к. будет просто "**Allow**"). Так же, текст на эмуляторе от Android Studio различается с физическим устройством несмотря на то что версии систем и устройства подобраны одинаково.

Где я могу найти решение данной проблемы ? Спасибо.

Comment: "автоматизирую действия с помощью AccessibilityServices" - вы случаем с automation не перепутали?

Comment: Нет, не перепутал. Мне нужно чтобы программа выполняла автоустановку программ для людей с ограниченными возможностями. AccessibilityService получает событие с экрана, потом получает компоненты, которые там есть и нажимает на нужную кнопку.

Answer (score 1):

Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23168383/9363441) показано красиво как получить языки (имеется в виду код языка который сейчас в системе стоит):

```
Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()       ---> en      
Locale.getDefault().getISO3Language()   ---> eng 
Locale.getDefault().getCountry()        ---> US 
Locale.getDefault().getISO3Country()    ---> USA 
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayCountry() ---> United States 
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayName()    ---> English (United States) 
Locale.getDefault().toString()          ---> en_US
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage()---> English
Locale.getDefault().toLanguageTag()     ---> en-US
```

Вообще логика такая - вы создаете базовый `strings.xml` например английский:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>                       <resources>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="hello_name">Hello %s!</string>          
</resources>
```

дальше вы добавляете через мастера переводов новую локаль, например русский. Забрасываете туда все переводы строк из английского strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <string name="hello_world">Привет мир!</string>
   <string name="hello_name">Привет%s!</string>
</resources>
```

и дальше система сама решает какой файл взять. Например у вас в системе стоит английский язык, тогда система будет брать английский strings.xml. То какой файл выберет ось, не зависит от модели устройства, а только от языка который вы используете. Ресурса с переводами системы нет, все делается вручную. [Вот](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization) есть документация по вопросу локализации приложения. Так же [вот туториал](https://proandroiddev.com/what-is-android-app-localization-and-why-should-you-care-e4ba72f867fa), где прекрасно расписан принцип локализации вашего приложения. Вот как добавить новую локаль:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Туторил](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/locale.php) на русском с инструкцией по добавлению нового языка.

### UPDATE

Нашел [вот такой интересный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631278/useful-android-system-resources) на просторах интернета. В нем указывается что сама система может вам выдать разные стринги. Вот так же есть [такой issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36908899). И [вот тут](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.string.html) вроде как есть все строки которые присутствуют в системе. [Вот тут](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/strings.xml) тоже много системных строк.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но это не совсем то что мне нужно. Мне нужно нажимать по экрану вместо пользователя на элемент с текстом, который я (грубо говоря) не знаю. Допустим мне нужно сделать автоматическую установку программ для людей с ограниченными возможностями и когда показывает окно для установки у меня есть две кнопки одна "Отмена", другая "Установить". Но на англ вместо "Install" у меня может быть "Install app" что уже не равно слову "Установить", а мое приложение не ограничивается только двумя языками.

Мне нужно выяснить где система, а не мое приложение хранит языки в данном случае.

Comment: Спец. возможности позволяют нажимать на экран вместо пользователя. Это сделано для автоматизации процесса. Пользователь решает какие программы (сторонние) ему установить и программа проводит весь процесс сама. 

И вопрос состоит в том где система андроид хранит ресурсы локализаций ? То как она решает что приложение настройки называется "Настройки", а не "Опции", то есть откуда она берет текст для локализации UI интерфейса пользователя ?

Comment: Мне нужно не получить доступ извне, а лишь получить xml файл с локализацией для всего устройства, но в интернете так и не нашел. 

Грубо говоря, если произвести декомпиляцию системного приложения "Настройки" то внутри хранится часть ресурсов, которые есть в самом приложении, но не прям вся локализация приложения, а мне нужно получить всю локализацию. Если есть ссылки на кастомные прошивки, то не могли бы поделится ?

Comment: @ウラジスラフルバンウラジスラフルバン, обновил ответ, вроде нашел то что вам нужно, посмотрите, может хотя бы получилось уточнить то что вы ищете :)

Comment: спасибо большое ) Это не совсем то, но вы правильно уловили суть моего вопроса. Ниже оставил комментарий где нашел решение для моей проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо тем кто искал, последний ответ был почти то что мне нужно, но все же не то.

По счастливой случайности я читал статью на хабре про [скрытый API](https://xakep.ru/2016/09/15/android-hidden-api/) в Android и автор статьи указал ссылку на сайт где можно найти больше скрытых методов. К моему счастью на том же сайте находилось то что мне нужно.

Вот ["ресурсы"](http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/packages/apps/PackageInstaller/res/values-ru/strings.xml), которые я искал. На этом сайте много полезного так что надеюсь кому-то это поможет.